# Button ignores action when segued to a previous viewcontroller

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, xcode7, unwind-segue

So here is my current issue.

I want to unwind to a previous viewcontroller lets call it viewcontroller1. 
This works fine, except that the button action
 that is hooked up with the segue, also has a lot of other code written in it. However, when pressing the button xcode ignores the code thats already written.

So this is my question how do I make the button perform the written code and then engage the segue??

For the unwind segue I've created an empty action in ViewController1.

```
  @IBAction func unwindtoViewcontroller1(segue: UIStoryboardSegue){}
```

And hooked ViewController2 up with this segue action (using ViewController2:s exit button). 
Ive also set the segue to "revealviewcontrollerpushviewcontroller"

Thanks in advance for all the help I can get I am really stuck.

Best regards Albin

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it this way:
Open Assistant Editor, then control drag from the button that performs the unwind segue in ViewController 2 to create an IBAction. That's where all the code for the action you would like your button to do should go.
This action gets performed before the unwind segue function is called.
So your button will do both: action and unwind.
I have made a simple project to illustrate and printed the output to the console. The button in yellowVC performs an action before unwind.
So as you said, in the first ViewController (in my example the green one you have an IBAction for unwind segue

```
@IBAction func goBackToGreenVC(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {  
      print("go back")
}
```

Then in the second ViewController (in my case the yellow one), control drag from the button to Exit to set unwind segue and then also control drag from the button to Assistant Editor for an IBAction, something like:

```
@IBAction func goBackToGreenVCButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {  
     print("performing an action before unwind")  
}
```

[image: storyboard][image]